# Unable to access GitHub without using VPN or hotspot from mobile

Tags: github

I am unable to access GitHub either from the terminal or from any browser or device when I am using the WiFi. I am able to pull, push or execute any command related to Github from the terminal and access GitHub on the browser when I use the hotspot I created from the mobile.

And the other way that I am able to access GitHub on the browser is using VPN. When I use the git commands using the mobile hotspot I get the same error but I delete the key using the method they have mentioned and follow the process and enter the password and everything is fine. When I use the same method using the WiFi even though I enter the password correctly it denies me access.

The error I showing up on the terminal when I'm using wifi and executing any git command:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The RSA host key for github.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 103.59.214.106
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
`MY REMOTE HOST KEY`.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/mayank/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/mayank/.ssh/known_hosts:39
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/mayank/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "github.com"
RSA host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're connecting, you should verify the host key fingerprint matches [the ones that GitHub has posted on its website](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).  If they don't, then the reason you're seeing this is because you have a device which is intercepting your traffic.  That device could be your router or, if you're in a corporate environment, it could be something owned by your company.  Whatever it is, it's a security problem and should be disabled, removed, or fixed not to intercept outgoing port 22 traffic.

If the fingerprint does match, then the reverse has happened: you've inserted the wrong key into your known hosts file.  Run the command specified (`ssh-keygen -f "/home/mayank/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "github.com"`) and then attempt to connect again.  This time, verify the fingerprints match, and then the problem should be solved.

Comment: I got it resolved. Turns out my ISP had mistakenly disabled the port-22 which was the reason it was happening. Thank you for your response. Appreciated.

Comment: I think my ISP is also blocking port 22. I ended up modifying my `~/.ssh/config` file to have `ssh.github.com` use port 443 instead (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Once**

This might be helpful if you delete line 39 which is generating error

https://serverfault.com/questions/6233/how-to-remove-strict-rsa-key-checking-in-ssh-and-whats-the-problem-here

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Tried that as well. The error showing after execution of the alternate command in that article shows me the following error:
# Host github.com found: line 39
/home/mayank/.ssh/known_hosts is not a valid known_hosts file.
Not replacing existing known_hosts file because of errors

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was modified C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts files where github.com (with other sites) was set to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @bk2204's answer, and [it didn't work](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) for me.

I ended up having to use another SSH port for GitHub as a temporary workaround.

It's likely that my ISP is just blocking requests to port `22`. GitHub also supports SSH over port 443, which is less likely to be blocked by ISPs.

I ended up modifying my SSH configuration to use port 443 for GitHub connections like so:

```bash
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

Add the following lines to the config file:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Now try doing a `git pull` or `git push` again.